# Is it OK to execute "ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY" without changing anything?

Tags: mysql

My application has a table with a VARCHAR(25), I need to increase that for old and new users.

For new users I can just update the CREATE statement.
For old users I could execute "ALTER TABLE" on application startup.

At the moment I cannot know from what version the user is updating, so this leads to my question:
Is it OK to execute that alter statement on every startup even if nothing is going to change or should I implement a way to check the previous version?

Comment: You have a table for every user?

Comment: @P.Salmon every user has its own database.

Comment: I assume you have an executable that connects to a user specific server (e.g. user owned local server)? E.g. the user gets a new version of your executable, and that executable updates the (local) server?

Comment: @Solarflare yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the `ALTER TABLE` every time. If the column has already been changed previously, nothing happens.

Alternatively, you could check the column length before updating:

```
select CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA='db' and TABLE_NAME='table' and COLUMN_NAME='column'
```

Comment: I thought about checking the column length, but can't find a way to do that. The LENGTH() returns the length of a String, not the column's max length, right?

Comment: Added the query for the column length. As said, the `ALTER TABLE`-command does nothing when no change is needed, so checking the column length really brings no additional benefits.